# Dynamic Internet IP Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop Setup

Tags: 12.04, internet, dynamic-ip

Installed dual boot with Ubuntu 12.04 desktop and Win XP. On XP can/have set up my internet access to be on demand - click desktop shortcut/enter UN & PW/connects via router which is set to bridged mode. Do not want a connection that is always on. The XP setup gives a different IP address each time it is connected. Would like to do the same setup on Ubuntu.Plenty of advice on servers and connecting to LAN networks but nothing on standalone desktop systems. Would appreciate some advice on setup procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to setup pppoe connection on ubuntu is to use pppoeconfig.
Open terminal from the dash home or press Ctrl+Alt+T, execute this command

```
sudo pppoeconf
```

- It starts looking for pppoe access concentrator on eth0…
- Say yes on this configure on /etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider
- Say yes until you see this prompt, and enter the username.
- Then enter the password
- Say yes and OK on following pages and the network connection should
  be OK

You can use following commands to make a manual connection:

start with:

```
pon dsl-provider
```

stop with:

```
poff dsl-provider
```